# Find UK patent detail

Tags: search, uk

I am looking to see if I can patent a product in the UK, I have seen another company who sells a similar product to ours. I have done a patent search and they are in the process of registering a patent (patent pending), I have the patent number but when I search for it the details only come up as their company name and a short (3 words) description how do i see what it is that is being patented?

Comment: If a patent hasn't yet issued, you have an application number, not a patent number. If you provide the application number we can better help you search for the document.  Applications often have their claims changed before a patent is granted. Where have you tried searching.

Comment: Patent applications only become public 18 months after the filing date or the earliest priority date. Unlike most countries, the UK publishes the title of patent applications and the company shortly after the filing of the patent application. That seems to be the case here as you have only found 3 words. Feel free to share the number of the patent application to see if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @theEuropeist That comment would make an adequate answer considering we aren't getting any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Patent applications only become public 18 months after the filing date or the earliest priority date. Unlike most countries, the UK publishes the title of patent applications and the company shortly after the filing of the patent application. That seems to be the case here as you have only found 3 words.

Please share the number of the patent application to see if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

The [UK IPO patent information service is called IPSUM](https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum.htm). You can enter an application number, or publication number, to find all public details of an application. As others have said, there is also the [UK Register of Patents](https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-pj) in which a title is published when a patent is applied for (it also records other legal information about status changes for patents; it is a sort of log or diary of all UK patents).

Patent applications which are published will appear on other patent information services like Google Patents, various country's GlobalDossier sites (eg [USPTO GlobalDossier](https://globaldossier.uspto.gov/)), the [EPO's Espacenet service](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/). You can search for patents with those services, eg using the applicant name (usually a company) or the inventors names.

After filing for a patent an applicant requests a search using Form 9, within a 6-month target period the search is performed and then publication follows. As a priority date can be up to 12-months before the filing date, the publication date can be ~18-months after this (as @the Europeist mentioned). There are [UK factsheets on patent timelines and such here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/patent-fact-sheets).